How can I import ```IterableReadableStream``` class from langchain.js in a node project?
I want to import IterableReadableStream class in my project to generate an iterableStream of type IterableReadableStream<string> from IterableReadableStream<{answer:string,content:Document[]}>
Here is the code what I wanted to do:
`const stream = await Package.retrievalChain.stream({
input: textFeed,
});

const answerStream: ReadableStream<String> = new ReadableStream({
    async pull(controller) {
        try {
            for await (const chunk of stream) {
                if (chunk.answer != 'undefined')
                    controller.enqueue(chunk.answer);
            }
            controller.close();
        } catch (error: Error | any) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }

    },
});

console.log("---Readable Stream generated")
const iterableReadableStream = convertEventStreamToIterableReadableDataStream(answerStream);
try {
    for await (const chunk of iterableReadableStream) {
        process.stdout.write(`${chunk}`);
    }

} catch (error: Error | any) {
    console.log(error.message)
} finally {
}


// return new StreamingTextResponse(iterableReadableStream);
return new NextResponse('done', { status: 200 })`

I want to actually stream the response rather than invoke() it.
I want only the answer field in the resulting stream to be extracted and sent to frontend rather than the stream whose chunks is of type {answer:string,content:Document[]}
